# React native : useEffect display after render

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have this React Native code

```
    const showMessage = () => {
      const [message,setMessage] = useState('default message');
      useEffect(()=> {
        setMessage('new message')
      }, []);

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            {message}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    export default showMessage;
```

I know that `useEffect` runs after render, so does this mean that the app shows the 'default message' even for a micro-second (so if I record a video of the phone screen and make it mega slow (x100 slower I will be able to see 'default message') and then shows 'new message' , or it directly shows 'new message'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Default message will show.

To prevent that you should check message state and
return empty view.

If i was you i use null as a initial state

And

message === null && View